# "Оба эти" или "оба этих"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, числительные

"В силу этой причины оба эти понятия приобретают глубоко субъективную окраску". Как правильно: "оба эти" или "оба этих"?

Comment: Думаю, что правильно: оба этих понятия.  Вариант оба эти понятия - разговорный.  А вы как считаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово *понятия* является подлежащим и стоит в именительном падеже. Определение согласуется с подлежащим, следовательно тоже должно быть в именительном падеже: *эти понятия*

Comment: Подлежащее здесь "оба понятия". Слово "понятия" здесь всё-таки в родительном падеже.

Comment: Да, конечно. Невнимательно прочитала. Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 3):

Это предложение неправильно построено. Недопустимо использование местоимения ЭТИ, употреблённого во множественном числе, между числительным ОБА и  существительным.
  Дело в том, что при числительном ОБА имя существительное употребляется не в именительном, а в **РОДИТЕЛЬНОМ** падеже и в **ЕДИНСТВЕННОМ ЧИСЛЕ**. Ср.: оба солдата, оба друга, оба выражения. 
***Словарь Ушакова:***
***О́БА,*** обоих, муж. и ср.; Обе, обеих, жен., числ. колич. (оба и обе сочетаются с***** род**.** ед.** имени, остальные формы согласуются в роде и падеже с именем).

Предложение должно выглядеть так: "***В силу этой причины  оба  понятия приобретают глубоко субъективную окраску"***.  Так будет грамотно, и, кроме того, Вы избавитесь от повтора слова "это".

Comment: Что значит "в единственном числе"? Я не совсем понял..

Comment: Сравните: в родительном падеже после ОБА: оба солдат (мн.ч., неправ.) - оба солдата (ед.ч.), оба понятий(мн.ч., неправ.) - оба понятия (ед.ч.).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! То есть **эти** будет согласовываться только с именительным падежом, в то время как **оба** - только с родительным, да еще в ед. числе. А форма "этих" будет требовать род. падеж, мн. число. Поэтому теоретически нельзя использовать сочетания "оба эти" "оба этих" (а также "обе эти(х)". Но в корпусе обнаруживается [784 вхождения](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EE%E1%E0+%FD%F2%E8) для "**оба эти**" и 138 для "**оба этих**". Интересно.

Answer (score 0):

http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliv-soglasovanie-opredeleniy-i-prilozheniy/ss-193-opredelenie-pri-sushchestvitelnom-zavisyashchem-ot-chislitelnyh-dva-tri-chetyre

Исходя из данного параграфа, допустим вариант "оба этих понятия", поскольку и в том, и в другом случае мы имеем дело с остатками двойственного числа существительного в современных восточнославянских языках.

В то же время определение перед числительным или обособленное определение ставится в именительном падеже независимо от рода существительного: большие два стола; две картины, писанные маслом, висели на стене; два письма, написанные братом, встревожили меня.

Исключение составляют прилагательные "целый", "полный", "добрый", которые обычно стоят в родительном падеже и перед числительным (целых две недели, полных три месяца), хотя в живой речи очень распространено использование формы именительного падежа.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Оба эти" или "оба этих"? От предмета вопроса не слишком ли отошли? Пример с «целых две недели» надо понимать в пользу правильности «этих обе недели»?